# WCF Service Shared DLL Types Not Generating

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, dll

I have a WCF service that is referencing a DLL that is also used by the client.  When I try to generate the service reference using the IDE in Visual Studio, I get a blank reference.cs file.  The only way I can get the service reference to generate a populated reference.cs is if I select the option to not include the dll in the list of referenced assemblies.  This of course is undesirable as the service reference then generates with types that are of the service and not of the DLL.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what I can do to have the service and the client still reference the same DLL?

Comment: View your warnings in the Error List after generating a client.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, the issue was being caused by something wrong with the builds I was using for both the .DLL and the service reference. Doing a clean/rebuild of both of them and then adding the service reference with the option to "Reuse types in all referenced assemblies" got the whole thing working.